# Posch-Teller potential

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I made a matlab code to find numerical solutions to the Schrödinger equation independent of time, and it works very good, the eigenfunctions always are what they should be, the problem is in the eigenvalues, they never make any sense.

To prove that my code work I have to use it to calculate the first 10 eigenvalues of the poschl teller potential, which are [super easy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B6schl%E2%80%93Teller_potential) to find by hand, but my code gives me a continuos range of non degenerate eigenvalues.

This is my code

```
%Variables.
N=1000;
x=linspace(-1,1,N);
lambda=4;
%Potential
v = (lambda*(lambda+1)/2)*((sech(x)).^2);
%Derivation matrix
D = (-(diag(ones(N,1),0)*(-2)+diag(ones(N-1,1),-1)+diag(ones(N- 1,1),+1)) - diag(v));
%This is to make it a bound state
D(1,N)=0;
D(N,1)=0;
%get eigenfunctions 
[F,V]=eig(D);
eigenvalues=diag(V);
for m=1:5
fn=F(:,m);
figure
plot(x,fn);
disp('Eigenvalue')
disp(V(m,m))
end
```

Comment: It looks to me like you are not dividing by $h^2$ in writing the "second derivative" part of your matrix.

Comment: Try D = ((-N^2/8)*(diag(ones(N,1),0)*(-2)+diag(ones(N-1,1),-1)+diag(ones(N- 1,1),+1)) - diag(v)); Also, the D(1,N) and D(N,1) lines are not doing anything, because those entries are *already* zero. Is that intentional, or are you actually trying to enforce some boundary condition in your equation?